# Better way to store data in REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Language used : javascript with react / redux

My project : I have a multiple step form. At every step,when a user write something or check someting i'm using redux to store the state. I have one reducer but I'm creating an action for every step of the form

What i would like to do  : I would like to have only one action to update the state step by step.

What i'm doing now (working fine) :

my page who contain each step

```
const Form = () => {
 
  return ( 
      <div className="page">
        <form>
          {
            {
              1: <StepOne />,
              2: <StepTwo />,
              3: <StepThree />,
            }[buttonDatas.pageNumber]
          }
        </form>
      </div>
  
  );
};

export default Form;
```

here one example of a step component (stepOne)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { addName } from '../../../actions/form.action.js';
import { isEmpty } from '../../../middlewares/verification.js';

export const StepOne = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const usersList = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer);
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(addName(userName));
  }, [dispatch, userName]);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Select the user name</label>
      <select
        name="name"
        onChange={(e) => {
          const userSelected = e.target.value;
          setUserName(userSelected);
        }}
        defaultValue={'default'}
      >
        <option value="default" hidden disabled>
          Select a user
        </option>
        {!isEmpty(usersList[0]) &&
          usersList.map((user) => {
            return (
              <option key={user.id}>
                {user.fullName}
              </option>
            );
          })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

here my reducer  :

```
import {
  ADD_NAME,
  ADD_PHONE,
  ADD_ADDRESS,
} from '../actions/form.action';

const initialState = {
  userInfo: {
    name: '',
    phone : '',

  },
  address: ''
};

export default function formReducer(state = initialState, actions) {
  switch (actions.type) {
     
    case ADD_NAME:
      state = {
        ...state,
        userInfo: {
          name: actions.payload,
        },
      };
      return state;

    case ADD_PHONE:
      state = {
        ...state,
        userInfo: {
          phone: actions.payload,
        },
      };
      return state;

    case ADD_ADDRESS:
      state = {
        ...state,
        address: actions.payload,
        },
      };
      return state;
   
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to write it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create one object that includes all the necessary property values throughout your multi-step form wizard layout and maintain only one action to save the data in the Redux store. Instead of making each action item for a single property of the identical form.

hereby am giving you a reference which will help you to organise your code based on your requirement.

I will recommend you to go through below two links:

1. [Redux Form multi-step wizard form](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/wizard/)
2. [Video Tutorial of creating a multi-step form using react Hooks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOxP4k9f5rk&ab_channel=PedroTech).

Answer (score 0):

With the indications of nimish, i've used redux toolkit and react-hook-form and it's working fine.

What i've change :
Create a slice file (for my reducer and action ) with redux toolkit

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
 
const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'form',
  initialState: {
    userInfo: {
      name: '', 
      phone: ''
    },

    address: ''
     

  },
  reducers: {
    selectUserName: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo.name = action.payload;
    },
    addUserPhone: (state, action) => {
      state.userInfo.phone = action.payload;
    },
    addAddress: (state, action) => {
      state.address = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const reducer = formSlice.reducer;

export const {
  selectUserName,
  addUserPhone,
  addAddress,
} = formSlice.actions;
```

use it in my userInfo component

```
import React from 'react';
import { userName } from './userName';
import { userPhone } from './userPhone';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import {
  selectUserName,
  addUserPhone,
} from '../../../reducer/form.slice';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export const UserInfo = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const state = useSelector((state) => state.reducer);

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {},
  });

  const onChange = (data) => {
    dispatch(selectUserName(data.name);
    dispatch(addUserPhone(data.phone));
 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="title"> Step One : Information User</h2>
      <form onChange={handleSubmit(onChange)} className="form">
        <userName register={register} />
        <userPhone register={register} />
       
      </form>

//to see your result 
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
```

in the child comp

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { isEmpty } from '../../../middlewares/verification.js';

export const UserName = ({ register }) => {
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer);

  return (
    <div className="form_group">
        <label>Select the user name</label>
      <select
        className="select"
        name="name"
        {...register('userName')}
        defaultValue={'default'}
      >
        <option value="default" hidden disabled>
          Select a user        
</option>
        {!isEmpty(userList[0]) &&
          userList.map((user) => {
            return (
              <option value={user.fullName} key={user.mail}>
                {user.fullName}
              </option>
            );
          })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

thank you.